# How to change popover width in a specific box (ID)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 I would like to change only one of the popovers which I am using in my template and is located in a div called `wrap`.

As you can see I tried

```
#wrap .popover {
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

but it is not working! How can I fix this?

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true, 
    content: function() {
          return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
});
```

```css
#wrap .popover {
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div id="wrap">
    <a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" role="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="login" class="btn btn-default">Send</a>
    <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
        <div class="well well-sm" style="margin-top:16px;  padding-top:14px; padding-bottom:0px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="text">
                        <span class="btn input-group-addon" id="send-app">Send</span>
                        </div>
                        <p class="help-block animated"></p>
                    </div>
                <div id="result"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this using bootstrap is to call the template method of the popover and then you can add class to template html to style or increase its width in your case.

The popover always loads outside the wrapper elemenet **so your css #wrap .popover{max-width:600px} was not working**. So  I have called the popover by **adding class to the anchor** `.popCustom` which will initialize the popover and in the template:

```
template: '<div class="popover NewClassAdded"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
```

added the custom class `NewClassAdded` which will be now the new base for the popover and you can now easily customize your popover.

```
.popover.NewClassAdded{max-width:600px;}
```

> Here is the working example:

```js
$(".popCustom").popover({
    html: true, 
    template: '<div class="popover NewClassAdded"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
 content: function() {
          return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
});
```

```css
.popover.NewClassAdded{max-width:600px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div id="wrap">
 <a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" role="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="login" class="btn btn-default popCustom">Send</a>
 <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
  <div class="well well-sm" style="margin-top:16px;  padding-top:14px; padding-bottom:0px;">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
      <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="text">
      <span class="btn input-group-addon" id="send-app">Send</span>
      </div>
      <p class="help-block animated"></p>
     </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify container inside your script  `container:'#wrap'`

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true, 

    container:'#wrap',
    content: function() {
          return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
});
```

then give a custom style to your popover

```
.popover{
    max-width: 600px!important; /* Max Width of the popover (depending on the container!) */
}
```

check out this snippet

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true, 
  
 container:'#wrap',
 content: function() {
          return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
});
```

```css
.popover{
    max-width: 600px!important; /* Max Width of the popover (depending on the container!) */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
 <div id="wrap">
  <a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" role="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="login" class="btn btn-default">Send</a>
  <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
   <div class="well well-sm" style="margin-top:16px;  padding-top:14px; padding-bottom:0px;">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="input-group">
       <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="text">
       <span class="btn input-group-addon" id="send-app">Send</span>
       </div>
       <p class="help-block animated"></p>
      </div>
     <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but you are still using a generic slector `.popover` !